# Get HTTP request message from Request object in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I need to somehow extract plain HTTP request message from a `Request` object in Scrapy (so that I could, for example, copy/paste this request and run from Burp).

So given a [`scrapy.http.Request`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects) object, I would like to get the corresponding request message, such as e.g.

```
POST /test/demo_form.php HTTP/1.1
Host: w3schools.com

name1=value1&name2=value2
```

Clearly I have all the information I need in the `Request` object, however trying to reconstruct the message manually is error-prone as I could miss some edge cases. My understanding is that Scrapy first converts this `Request` into `Twisted` object, which then writes headers and body into a TCP transport. So maybe there's away to do something similar, but write to a string instead?

**UPDATE**

I could use the following code to get `HTTP 1.0` request message, which is based on [`http.py`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http.py). Is there a way to do something similar with `HTTP 1.1` requests / [`http11.py`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py), which is what's actually being sent? I would obviously like to avoid duplicating code from `Scrapy`/`Twisted` frameworks as much as possible.

```
factory = webclient.ScrapyHTTPClientFactory(request)
transport = StringTransport()
protocol = webclient.ScrapyHTTPPageGetter()
protocol.factory = factory protocol.makeConnection(transport)
request_message = transport.value()
print(request_message.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

As scrapy is open source and also has plenty of extension points, this should be doable.

The requests are finally assembled and sent out in scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py in `ScrapyAgent.download_request` ( https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py#L270 )

If you place your hook there you can dump the request type, request headers, and request body.

To place your code there you can either try monkey patching `ScrapyAgent.download_request` or to subclass `ScrapyAgent` to do the request logging, then subclass `HTTP11DownloadHandler` to use your Scrapy Agent and then set HTTP11DownloadHandler as new DOWNLOAD_HANDLER for http / https requests in your project's settings.py (for details see: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-handlers)

In my opinion this is the closest you can get to logging the requests going out without using a packet sniffer or a logging proxy (which might be a bit overkill for your scenario).

Comment: Well, yes, but the problem is whatever is done in `download_request` is still quite far from the resulting request. There are plenty of cases where `Twisted` modifies / augments headers further down the line, e.g. to add `host` if missing etc. I'm wondering if it's possible to just trick `Twisted` into writing the resulting request in a string, rather than having to copy-paste all the code?

Comment: Reading up a bit more on `Twisted`, I think what I want is to use a real `Agent`, but feed it with a dummy transport like `twisted.test.proto_helpers.StringTransport` which will just buffer the request in memory. I'll then copy-paste the code from `download_request` with the exception of using my `Agent` with `StringTransport`. Am I on the right track? Cannot seem to find any examples of doing the same thing.

Comment: Actually, it seems much easier than I thought.. Any drawback to simply doing this?
       `factory = webclient.ScrapyHTTPClientFactory(response.request)
        transport = StringTransport()
        protocol = webclient.ScrapyHTTPPageGetter()
        protocol.factory = factory
        protocol.makeConnection(transport)
        htmlRequest = transport.value()
        print(htmlRequest.decode("utf-8"))`

Comment: Well, one problem I can see is that it works off `http.py`, i.e. `HTTP 1.0` which is reflected in the request message it produces. Can this be done with `http11.py` in a similar way? P.S. got the idea for above from [these tests](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/7ad5156287e68e4f1658dab25449450293d3e6f9/tests/test_webclient.py)

Comment: Great idea. Some thoughts on this: 

1. I think you can run your code snippet directly in any parse method of the scraper on the response.request object that is passed into the parse method, but this only works if you get a response for your request

2. The structure in http11.py is a bit different, unfortunately. What might work is plugging your code around line 300 in http11.py ( https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/7b49b9c0f53396ac89cbd74930bc4c6e41d41901/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py#L299 ) as the request is completely built up at this point